# Python: My code creates multiple lists

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

> Every time I run my code it always creates multiple list in the run
>   time. I want all the usernames that I written to be placed all in one
>   list.

```
def Username_Lists():
        for i in range(5):
            name = input ('What is your name?: ')
            if name not in my_names:
                    my_names.append(name)
                    print (name)
                    print (my_names, file=p)
```

The execution looks like this:

```
['Bob']
['Bob', 'Mandy']
['Bob', 'Mandy', 'Batman']
['Bob', 'Mandy', 'Batman', 'Superman']
['Bob', 'Mandy', 'Batman', 'Superman', 'Spider-Man']
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Where are you defining `my_names`?

Comment: I only see a single list, printed 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print statement is within your for loop. Reduce the indentation if you only want it to print once after the loop has run.

```
def Username_Lists():
    for i in range(5):
        name = input ('What is your name?: ')
        if name not in my_names:
                my_names.append(name)
    print (name)
    print (my_names, file=p)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't create multiple lists, you just printed the list five times so that it looks like you created five lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should take your prints out of the loop, like here:

```
def Username_Lists():
    for i in range(5):
        name = input ('What is your name?: ')
        if name not in my_names:
                my_names.append(name)
    print (name)
    print (my_names, file=p)
```

And, to avoid repetition, you can also do the following:

```
def Username_Lists():
    for i in range(5):
        name = input ('What is your name?: ')
        my_names.append(name)

    # remove repetitions
    my_names = list(set(my_names))
    print (name)
    print (my_names, file=p)
```